# How to programmatically click on the screen of Windows Phone?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

In my application I have an ApplicationBarIconButton which hides under a popup menu when I click on it and reappears when I click on any other location on the screen. To test the application I want to programmatically click on any location on the screen. Does anyone knows how I can implement clicking on the phone screen?

Answer (score 1):

Could you be more specific about what Controls you are using to implement these popup menus and hide actions?

Instead of trying to programmatically click on a location, you could try an alternative approach, such as calling your popup's "hide" and "show"-type methods.

Comment: I am getting all the controls through VisualTreeHelper and access the Popup menu using VisualTreeHelper.GetOpenPopups(). What I am trying to do is mimicking users actions and basically a user cannot change the visibility of popup unless he/she taps the phone screen. So, I need to somehow programmatically tap the screen.

Comment: It does! However, the best option still is to programmatically click on the screen, but if this is not possible, IsOpen is the bypass!